# How to make a continuous fill legend appear discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am using `gganimate` with `colorspace` to demonstrate partial pooling in Bayesian hierarchical models, and I like the aesthetic transition I have accomplished, but I would prefer for the fill legend for "Prior" to appear as two discrete boxes (as it would with `scale_fill_discrete`) but I seem to need to pretend my distribution field is continuous in order to trigger the nice transition that `scale_fill_continuous_sequential()` is enabling.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(colorspace)
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
SIMS <- 1e3
df <- 
    tibble(
        a = rbeta(SIMS, 600, 400),
        b = rbeta(SIMS, 650, 350)
    ) |> 
    pivot_longer(
        everything(),
        names_to = 'distribution',
        values_to = 'values'
    ) |> 
    mutate(distribution = factor(distribution, levels = c('a','b')))

df |> 
    ggplot(aes(
        x = values, 
        fill = as.integer(distribution)
        )) + 
    geom_density() + 
    colorspace::scale_fill_continuous_sequential(
        palette = "Blues 3", 
        begin = 0.1, end = .9,
        breaks = c(1,2)
        ) +
    transition_states(
        states = distribution,
        transition_length = 1,
        state_length = 1,
        wrap = TRUE) + 
    labs(fill = "Prior")
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can use the `guide` argument to your fill scale, and pass `guide = guide_legend()`.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. There are several other packages required to make it work. I get errors in `mutate`, `pivot_longer`, and `transform_path`. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Can confirm the suggestion by @Axeman produces the result you want.

Comment: Perhaps replace your current scale with `colorspace::scale_fill_binned_sequential(palette = "Blues 3", begin = 0.1, end = 0.9)`?

Comment: guide=guide_legend() did the trick. If @Axeman would post this as an answer I'd gladly accept it as correct. 
colorspace::scale_fill_continuous_sequential(
        guide = guide_legend(),
        palette = "Blues 3", 
        begin = 0.1, end = .9,
        breaks = c(1,2)
        )

Comment: @alexwhitworth thank you I have added the omitted package